# How do I replace On Error Resume Next with try-catch?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated a few controls from VB6 to VB.Net and one of the read-only properties has "On Error Resume Next." Because of this, the property is not throwing any error and it will return a value always.

Now I have replaced this with try-catch and I want your guys' opinion whether the try-catch implementation holds good or need any changes.

Below, I have shown the original code as well as the try-catch implementation code.

Original wizard migrated code

```
Public ReadOnly Property TotalAmount() As String
    Get
        'On Error Resume Next
        Dim intIndex As Short
        Dim numFS As Short
        Dim totalAmount As Double
        With m_udtProperties_READ   
        
        numFS = CShort(UBound(m_udtProperties_READ.FundSource))  

            If numFS >= 0 Then
                For intIndex = 0 To numFS
                  
 totalAmount = totalAmount +      
CDbl(m_udtProperties_READ.FundSource(intIndex).FromSide.Amount)
                    
                Next
            End If
            TotalAmount= CStr(totalAmount)

        End With

    End Get
```

Try catch implementation code.

```
    Public ReadOnly Property TotalAmount() As String
    Get
        
        Dim intIndex As Short
        Dim numFS As Short
        Dim totalAmount As Double
        With m_udtProperties_READ
            Try
                numFS = CShort(UBound(m_udtProperties_READ.FundSource))
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            If numFS >= 0 Then
                For intIndex = 0 To numFS
                    Try
                        totalAmount = totalAmount + CDbl(m_udtProperties_READ.FundSource(intIndex).FromSide.Amount)
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                Next
            End If
            TotalAmount = CStr(totalAmount)

        End With

    End Get
End Property
```

is there any better way than above?

Comment: This property could be refactored! It depends on what is the exception. If it's just null exception then it can be replaced with if statement. I would also suggest you turn Option String On, you might have a problem with that last line.

Comment: You should never "swallow" errors in my opinion. They should either throw or they should have an explicit behavior defined in the catch.

Comment: You don't replace `On Error Resume Next` with `Try...Catch`.  The latter is structured exception handling while the former is unstructured.  `On Error Resume Next` is still supported in VB.NET so, if you need the behaviour of `On Error Resume Next` then use `On Error Resume Next`.  The thing is, you should almost never want that behaviour.  If an exception is thrown, you should never simply continue executing unless you know for sure that the app is in a safe state.  If you don't even know what exception was thrown, how can you know that it's safe to continue?

Comment: What you should be doing is adding `Try...Catch` blocks where it is reasonable to do so, i.e. where you know exactly which exception(s) can reasonably be thrown and how to clean up after them, and then handling the `UnhandledException` event of the application to log the rest and exit gracefully.

Answer (score 4):

`on error resume next` is nasty when you need to convert code from vb6 to .net.

Basically, it means to simply ignore any error that comes after it and continue with the code execution right from the code row after the one that threw the error.

In .Net, doing the equivalent thing would mean that each row after where the `on error resume next` was, should be wrapped in a `try...catch` block with an empty catch.

Obviously, this is not practical nor is it good practice (In fact, it's a very bad practice to swallow exceptions).

Lucky for everyone that translates code, not every row is likely to throw an exception.
You need to isolate the danger zones in your translated code and only wrap them in `try...catch`.

I would recommend not to swallow the exceptions but propagate them to where they can be handled - so my advise is to do refactoring instead of just translating.